# $request variable empty after a post

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I'm facing this weird problem on CakePHP, when I try to login into the administration of my website locally (/users/login), I enter my username and password and works just fine
but after I uploaded it to a remote server, the same code, sambe database won't allow the user to login, it says the username/password is invalid, but after a few hours trying to figure out what was going on I found that the variable **$request** inside the **authenticate** method from FormAuthenticate.php is basically empty, it's coming like this into the remote server:

```
object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login',
        'named' => array(),
        'pass' => array()
    )
    data => array()
    query => array()
    url => 'users/login/'
    base => ''
    webroot => '/'
    here => '/users/login/'
}
```

however, the same page, running locally returns:

```
object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login',
        'named' => array(),
        'pass' => array()
    )
    data => array(
        'User' => array(
            'password' => '*****',
            'username' => 'admin'
        )
    )
    query => array()
    url => 'users/login/'
    base => ''
    webroot => '/'
    here => '/users/login/'
}
```

I tried to find anything that might be causing this but still no luck, I'm new to CakePHP so I might be missing something, thanks!!

---

update #1, here's my UserController::login method

```
public function login() {
        $this->layout = 'default_admin';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

---

update #2: I've changed the form method from "post" to "get" using the developers tools from chrome and then on UserController::login() I changed to:
    ...
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
    ...
and then It worked, but I need it to work with "post" method though =\

Comment: Can you share your `UsersController::login()` method with us?

Comment: @Jelmer I just updated my question with the method, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the server needed a restart. I've included these two lines to test the fileupload component on the .htaccess file:

> php_value upload_max_filesize 9999999999M
>
> php_value post_max_size 9999999999M

Then it started acting weird as described above, so I decided to restart the server and I got the following error message:

> "PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of XXX bytes exceeds the limit of -XXX bytes in Unknown on line 0"

Googling it I saw it had something to do with file sizes so I decided to change the value from "*9999999999M*" to "*2147483647*" and restarted the server and everything is working just fine now.

Sorry for such a rookie mistake, I'm really new to PHP and Cake and I thought I didn't have to restart the server whenever I uploaded new files.

Comment: What kind of files were you uploading? Because you shouldn't have to restart the server when uploading files. At least, I have never had to do that before. Or were you editing the php.ini file?

Comment: @Jelmer indeed I edited the php.ini, so that's the reason why I had to restart the server? I didn't know about that thanks a lot =D

Comment: Yes. Because Apache needs to "reread" the file. It won't if it hasn't been restarted :) Maybe a reload will do, but I am not quite sure about that though.